# Spark - size limit on filter predicates in getPartitionsByFilter()

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, apache-spark-sql, hive-metastore

By default Spark, when using external Hive metastore, will attempt to delegate partition pruning to HMS itself. For that, in [`HiveShim.getPartitionsByFilter()`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-3.2/sql/hive/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/hive/client/HiveShim.scala#L864) it will convert filters to the dialect understood by HMS, while skipping over unsupported predicates or those defined on non-partition columns:

```
  :
  override def getPartitionsByFilter(
      hive: Hive,
      table: Table,
      predicates: Seq[Expression]): Seq[Partition] = {

    // Hive getPartitionsByFilter() takes a string that represents partition
    // predicates like "str_key=\"value\" and int_key=1 ..."
      val filter = convertFilters(table, predicates)

      if (filter.isEmpty) {
        getAllPartitionsMethod.invoke(hive, table).asInstanceOf[JSet[Partition]]
      } else {
        logDebug(s"Hive metastore filter is '$filter'.")
        ...
  :
```

My question: Is there any limitation on how long the string representing the predicates after conversion can be? Please note I'm not asking about JVM's physical limit (2GB), rather what Hive client and Hive metastore itself will support.